# Solve the equation $\sqrt{x+5}=5-x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Solve the equation $\sqrt{x+5}=5-x^2$. I have tried to make the substitution $x=\sqrt{5}\tan^2 \theta$ and wanted to make use of the identity $\tan^2\theta+1=\sec^2\theta$ but it didn't work out. I also tried to make the substitution $y=x+5$ but it lead to nowhere. Since this was a contest problem, I believe there is a short, elegant and elementary solution, please helps.

Comment: Did you try the substitution $x=5\tan^2 \theta$?

Comment: Put $x = 5\tan^2 \theta$. Then, we have $$\sqrt{\sec^2 \theta} = 5(1-\tan^2 \theta)\sec^2\theta$$

Comment: OMG I got it, thanks so much guys!

Comment: Why not squaring both sides and factoring the resultng equation ?

Comment: @Peter, I tried but I couldn't factorize it.

Comment: It leads to $$(x^2-x-5)(x^2+x-4)=0$$

Comment: Do you mind showing me the intermediate steps? Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I did not factor it by hand. But you can use kroneckers method to do this. Furthermore, not all soltuions are solutions to the original equation.

Comment: Too bad it's not $\sqrt{x+5}=x^2-5$, since it has a beautiful inverse function solution. Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+5}$. Then $f(x)^2-5=x$ and so $f$ is the inverse of $x^2-5$. Therefore, since $\sqrt{x+5}, x^2-5$ are not identical functions, solutions happen iff $x^2-5=x$, i.e. $x^2-x-5=0$, which is actually one of the factors in Peter's equation (squaring led to the extraneous solutions to $-\sqrt{x+5}=5-x^2$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Hint:

the equation  equivalen to
$$x^4-10x^2-x+20=0$$
Because there is no $x^3$ in the equation and the coefficient of $x^4$ is $1$ , so we can use the following
$$(x^2-x+A)(x^2+x+B)=x^4-10x^2-x+20$$

Answer (score 7):

Here $5+x\geq 0\Rightarrow x\geq -5$ and $5-x^2\geq 0\Rightarrow x^2-\left(\sqrt{5}\right)^2\leq 0\Rightarrow -\sqrt{5}\leq x \leq \sqrt{5}$

So we get $-\sqrt{5}\leq x \leq \sqrt{5}.$

Now Let $\sqrt{5+x}=y\;,$ Then $$y^2=5+x \tag{1}$$

and equation convert into $$y=5-x^2\Rightarrow x^2=5-y\tag{2}$$

So $$y^2-x^2 = 5+x-(5-y)=(y+x)\Rightarrow (y^2-x^2)=(y+x)$$

So $$(y+x)\cdot(y-x)-(y+x) =0\Rightarrow (y+x)\cdot \left[y-x-1\right]=0$$

So either $y=x$ or $y=x+1$

$\bullet \; $ If $y=x\;,$ Then put into $y^2=5+x\Rightarrow x^2=5+x$

So we get $$\displaystyle x^2-x-5=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+20}}{2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{21}}{2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle x=\frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2}.$$ bcz here $-\sqrt{5}\leq x\leq \sqrt{5}$

$\bullet \; $ If $y=1+x\;,$ Then put into $y^2=5+x\Rightarrow (1+x)^2=5+x$

So we get $$1+x^2+2x=5+x\Rightarrow \displaystyle x^2+x-4=0\Rightarrow x= \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle x= \frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$ bcz here $-\sqrt{5}\leq x\leq \sqrt{5}$

So final solution is $\displaystyle x = \left\{\displaystyle  \frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\;, \frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2} \right\}$

Answer (score 3):

First, this condition must be satisfied $x^2 \le 5$.

Denote $y = \sqrt{x+5}$, then

$$\begin{align}\iff \cases{y = 5-x^2\\x=5-y^2}
\implies (x-y) = -(x^2-y^2)
\implies (x-y)(1+x+y) = 0
\end{align}$$
If $ x = y$, we have $x+5 = x^2\iff x = (1-\sqrt{21})/2$  (we remove the second root as it does not satisfy the condition $x^2\le 5$).

If $x+y+1 = 0$, we have $x+5 = (x+1)^2 \iff x = (\sqrt{17}-1)/2$ (we remove the second root as it does not satisfy the condition $x^2\le 5$).

We conclude that the equation has only two roots
$$\color{red}{x \in \left\{\frac{1-\sqrt {21}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2}\right\}}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in \mathbb R$ then we need $5\geq x^2$. Upon squaring the equation we get that

$$x+5 = 5^2+x^4-5(2x^2)$$ which becomes $$5^2-5(2x^2+1)+x^4-x=0$$ and by the quadratic formula $$5 = \frac{2x^2+1\pm \sqrt{(2x^2+1)^2-4(x^4-x)}}2$$ ie $$10=2x^2+1\pm \sqrt{1+4x^2+4x}$$ ie $$10 =2x^2+1\pm (2x+1)$$

This can be resolved into two cases:
$$0 = x^2-x-5$$ or $$0=x^2+x-4$$

Then, checking the four roots, we note that two do not satisfy the initial constraint. Thus, $$x \in \left\{\frac{1-\sqrt {21}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Several answers identify the quadratic factor equations

$x^2-x-5=0$

$x^2+x-4=0$

and from these we get four candidate roots $(1\pm\sqrt{21})/2,(-1\pm\sqrt{17})/2$. This answer deals with the problem of identifying which roots give nonnegative values for $5-x^2$ to match the requited nonnegative sqtare root in $\sqrt{x+5}$.

Rather than resort to numerical calculation, we can read the correct roots directly from the quadratic factor equations. We look first at the factor equation

$x^2-x-5=0,x^2\le5.$

We can eliminate the $x^2$ term to obtain the linear inequality

$x\le0,$

which is satisfied specifically by the negative root. Thus $x=(1-\sqrt{21})/2$.

Similarly

$x^2+x-4=0,x^2\le5$

leads to the inequality

$x\ge-1.$

This might allow the negative root of the qadratic equation $x^2+x-4=0$ if that were $\ge-1$. But then the positive root would not match with the fact that the sum of the roots must be $-1$, and so we find that the negative root of the quadratic equation is out of range. Thus in this case only the positive root $x=(-1+\sqrt{17})/2$.

So

$x\in\{(1-\sqrt{21})/2,(-1+\sqrt{17})/2\}.$